# JavaScript can I directly access to a property inside a property in the object?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, key

In this object, I want to print out an array in the form of [userName, skills]. I know that these objects don't have indexes. Is it possible to detect the `skills` property and only print out the value of that?

```js
const users = {
  Alex: {
    email: 'alex@alex.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'],
    age: 20,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 30
  },
  Asab: {
    email: 'asab@asab.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'Redux', 'MongoDB', 'Express', 'React', 'Node'],
    age: 25,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 50
  },
  Brook: {
    email: 'daniel@daniel.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React', 'Redux'],
    age: 30,
    isLoggedIn: true,
    points: 50
  }
}
```

I first tried the code below but there was an error that it cannot read properties of undefined (reading 0).

```js
let userId = Object.keys(users);  //(3) ['Alex', 'Asab', 'Brook']

for (let i = 0; i < userId.length; i++) {
  let userSkills = users.userId[i].skills;
  console.log(userId, userSkills);
}
```

Is it the only way that I check all the skills one by one like below?

```js
console.log(users.Alex.skills);
console.log(users.Asab.skills);
console.log(users.Brooks.skills);
```

Comment: You can't use [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#dot_notation) with variables, you need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation). `let userSkills = users[userId[i]].skills;` (and it looks like you want to log just the current user per iteration, so `console.log(userId[i], userSkills);`)

Comment: duplicate: [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, you should use bracket notation.

Links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

https://javascript.info/object

Also, you can use this to shorten your code:

```
userId.forEach(user => console.log(users[user].skills));
```

About array methods you can read here:

https://javascript.info/array-methods

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will work for you

```
let userId = Object.keys(users);  //(3) ['Alex', 'Asab', 'Brook']
for (let i = 0; i < userId.length; i++) {
  let userSkills = users[userId[i]].skills;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const users = {
  Alex: {
    email: 'alex@alex.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'],
    age: 20,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 30
  },
  Asab: {
    email: 'asab@asab.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'Redux', 'MongoDB', 'Express', 'React', 'Node'],
    age: 25,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 50
  },
  Brook: {
    email: 'daniel@daniel.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React', 'Redux'],
    age: 30,
    isLoggedIn: true,
    points: 50
  }
}

for (const element in users) {
  console.log(users[element].skills);
}
```

Comment: `for...in` is not as clearcut as this as it will also iterate inherited properties. see my comment on @B_Joker s answer.

Comment: it will iterate only thru enumerable props so the solution is valid for the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries` and map for it

```js
const users = {
  Alex: {
    email: 'alex@alex.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'],
    age: 20,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 30
  },
  Asab: {
    email: 'asab@asab.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'Redux', 'MongoDB', 'Express', 'React', 'Node'],
    age: 25,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    points: 50
  },
  Brook: {
    email: 'daniel@daniel.com',
    skills: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React', 'Redux'],
    age: 30,
    isLoggedIn: true,
    points: 50
  }
}

const resultArray = Object.entries(users).map(([user, {skills}]) => [user, skills])
const resultObject = Object.entries(users).map(([user, {skills}]) => ({user, skills}))

console.log(resultArray)
console.log(resultObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let userId = Object.keys(users);  //(3) ['Alex', 'Asab', 'Brook']

userId.forEach(u=> {
    console.log(users[u].skills);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there -

```
for (let i = 0; i < userId.length; i++) {
  let userSkills = users[userId[i]].skills;
  console.log(userId[i], userSkills);
}
```

Use Bracket Notation instead of Dot Notation.
Because all the time dot notation is not acceptable. Like - .number, .dependingValue, .anyCalculation, numericValue.something

Javascript mixes up decimal.

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Answer (score -1):

```
    for (name in users) {
      console.log([name, ...users[name].skills])
    }
```

Comment: Don't just post code unrelated to the errors the OP is encountering. While this may output the desired result, take the time to explain what you have done with links to relevant documentation when appropriate. The OP's code is fine, if a little round about, but is not working due to a minor syntax error which when learned will lead to better understanding in general. Also `for...in` may lead to other, unexpected outcomes [Iterating over own properties only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#iterating_over_own_properties_only)